# Magento - can't save changed customer GroupId with observer for newsletter_subscriber_save_before event

Tags: magento, events, observers

I built an observer for the `newsletter_subscriber_save_before event;` this gets fired when a customer subscribes/unsubscribes for newsletters.
I need to change this customers groupID accordingly. It seems i can change the GroupId, but i can't manage to save it. If i call in my code the `$customer->save()` - method, i run into an infinite loop; same occurs if i try to hook into the `newsletter_subscriber_save_after` event.

Anyone can help me? Would be much appreciated!

Here's my code in Observer.php :

```
public function newsletter_subscriber_change($observer) {
    try {

        // get status of subscriber
        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();

        $status = $subscriber->getStatus();
        $email = $subscriber->getEmail();

        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());

        $customer->loadByEmail($email);

    // here i change the groupId
        $customer->setData( 'group_id', 9 );
    // if i check the group here, the change applied ...
        $customer_group = $customer->getGroupId();

        // i tried saving with following, but run into loop
        $customer->save(); 

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log("newsletter_subscriber_change observer failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to do `$customer->setIsSubscribed(true)->save();` - ahh that won't work never mind, sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got infinite loop because Mage_Newsletter also capture `customer_save_after` event to save subscribe data.
You can update group id by raw query like bellow:

```
public function newsletter_subscriber_change($observer) {
    try {

        // get status of subscriber
        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();

        $status = $subscriber->getStatus();
        $email = $subscriber->getEmail();

        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());

        $customer->loadByEmail($email);

        $adapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

        /* @var $conn Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface */
        $conn = $adapter->getConnection('core_write');

        $update = 'UPDATE ' . $customer->getResource()->getTable('customer/customer_enity')
                . ' SET group_id = ? WHERE entity_id = ?';

        $conn->query($update, array(9, $customer->getId()));

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log("newsletter_subscriber_change observer failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ndlinh, your solution works for me. But, for my understanding: i experimented around a little more, and if i subscribe for newsletter (with logged in customer) in frontend via template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml, the customer_save_after event is not fired. It is fired only if i subscribe for newsletter in template/customer/form/newsletter.phtml . so i don't understand why i get this loop in the first case, or why i can't directly (without raw query) access and modify the customer group id.

Comment: As I said above, you capture `newsletter_subscriber_save_before ` event to change customer group. Mage_Newsletter module also capture `customer_save_after` to save subscriber. In your `newsletter_subscriber_change` method, you call `$customer->save(); `, it will fire `customer_save_after` event, then Mage_Newsletter handle this event and save subscriber, Mage_Newsletter will fire `newsletter_subscriber_save_before `, then your module capture this event, then call `$customer->save(); `, it will fire `customer_save_after` again, then it go to infinite loop.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, now i got it. i was thinking the wrong way around.